# Error with subprocess

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, mime-type

during installation of enlightenment, I asked to run following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Which results to sub-process error which is not understandable for me.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libefl-data libelementary-bin libelementary1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libefl-bin
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libefl-bin
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/470 kB of archives.
After this operation, 396 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 289041 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libefl-bin_201602061431-31496~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libefl-bin (201602061431-31496~ubuntu14.04.1) over (1.17.0-0trusty0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl-bin_201602061431-31496~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mime/packages/edje.xml', which is also in package libefl-data 1.17.0-0trusty0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl-bin_201602061431-31496~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea what is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Not sure how to handle that, but I guess it has something to do with broken mime type configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message says:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl-bin_201602061431-31496~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mime/packages/edje.xml', which is also in package libefl-data 1.17.0-0trusty0
```

That is, you have asked to install `libefl-bin_201602061431-31496~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb` (the `libefl` binaries package).

In trying to unpack the package (part of installing) it noticed that the `libefl-bin...` package was trying to overwrite (replace) a file, `/usr/share/mime/packages/edje.xml`, which is part of the `libefl-data 1.17.0-0trusty0` package. If two different packages try to install the same file, one of them will be unhappy.

You can either uninstall `libefl-data` (version `1.17.0-0trusty0`) first (probably safest) or, like @Ron: says, use the force options. Is the version of `libefl-bin...` the same as the version of `libefl-data`? Doesn't look like it. Will they interoperate happily? I don't think so. If you uninstall `libefl-data` first, then installing `libefl-bin...` will pull in a compatible version of `libefl-data`, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Forcefully overwriting the file should solve the problem in most of the cases:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl-bin_201602061431-31496~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```